# Entity Framework: Issue with adding new entity to the contex after deleting

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, associations

In my context I am deleting one of the existing entities. And in the same context I am trying to add a new entity with using code below:

```
        if (entity != null && EFContext.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            try
            {
                var entityName = entity.GetType().Name;             
                GetObjectContext.AddObject(entityName + "s", entity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

The problem I have is when I pass the new created entity to the method above, when it is checking the entity state, it throws exception:
*

> Adding a relationship with an entity which is in the Deleted state is
>   not allowed

I haven't made any relationship with the deleted entity, why would it throw this exception? I am trying to reproduce the issue on another simple project, but can't get to reproduce it there. 
Does anyone know why would EF would throw that exception?

**UPDATE:**
I have Student and a Backpack entity. Backpack references the Student(one to many). In my case I am deleting one of the backpacks and trying to create a new student entity. And when I am checking the object state I am getting the exception above.

Here is the call stack:
[image]

Comment: So does the entity only have primitive properties? You're sure it has no associated entities which could be the same as the ones associated to the deleted one?

Comment: @AlexPaven No, it is not referencing the deleted entity directly nor indirectly. I have Student and Backpack entity. Backpack references Student. I deleted one of the backpacks of the student. And now trying to create a new Student entity. When I check the newly created entity's state I am getting the exception. I also verified by creating an entity that has no association at all and I still get the same exception.

Comment: That sounds odd. I'd be curious what the stack trace of the exception is. But off the top of my head, given just this info, I can think of nothing that could cause this. Unless the way the primary keys are defined make EF decide that the newly added entity is the same as a deleted one, or something like that.

Comment: @AlexPaven I posted the call stack. also when I try see the newly added objects state after I get the exception, it says it is detached. So that is as expected, but why I am getting the exception is not clear to me either.

Comment: I don't have any suggestions except looking at every item in the ObjectStateManager and see if anything looks out of place. If there are similar items and you're not sure if they are really a reference to the same item, you can right click on the object in many places like the quick watch window or the tooltips and select Make Object ID, which will append something like '#1' or '$1' to the object when you look at it in the debugger to identify them more easily. Maybe do this at various steps in the execution and see if anything is added or changed in the context that you didn't expect.

Comment: @AlexPaven This is what I tried: I deleted the entity and before added the new one, wanted to read the Changes in the context and I get the same exception. I am not sure why this is happening? I tried deleting the entity that has non references and it works fine as expected. It is just with the entities that I have association. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

EFContext.Entry(entity) will add the entity to the context at this point.

Most likely the problem here is that the backpack you deleted may have a FK set to 0 after it was deleted or something?  If so, then when you add this new Student, that deleted one would end up being under the context of this new Student since it would have an ID of 0 yet.  As a temporary fix, try setting the PK of this new Student to -1 before calling Entry(entity) and see if that does anything.